# php foreach loop with urls from file

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to the status of urls which are stored in a text file

in my code i have:

```
$filestatus = file("urlsmartins_status.txt");
foreach ($filestatus as $filestate){
$filestatusurl = (file_get_contents("$filestate"));
$filestatusurlxml = new SimpleXMLElement ($filestatusurl);
print_r ($filestatusurlxml);
}
```

in the urlsmartin_status.txt i have 5 urls written

```
http://172.27.73.5:8080/api/service/
http://172.27.73.6:8080/api/service/
http://172.27.73.7:8080/api/service/
http://172.27.73.8:8080/api/service/
```

But when i execute the code i have the following result

PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://172.27.73.5:8080/api/service/
): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 OK
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in ...
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/html/pub/martin.php(56): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('')
#1 {main}
thrown in /opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/html/pub/martin.php on line 56

What am i missing here?

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: Or convert the content to the file to comma separated values CSV and loop through each instead

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is that the lines in your file are not "XML", hence SimpleXMLElement cannot be instantiated.

I get the same error like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it via

```
$filedata = file_get_contents('urlsmartins_status.txt');
$urls = explode("\n", trim($filedata));
foreach($urls as $key => $url) {
$filestatusurl = file_get_contents("$url");
$filestatusurlxml = new SimpleXMLElement ($filestatusurl);
print_r ($filestatusurlxml);
```